# Selecting two options and go to a html page

Tags: jquery

I have two `select` and i want to let jquery know if white selected and black selected go to https://stackoverflow.com/

```
<select id="filter-select">
 <option value="white">white</option>
 <option value="black">black</option>
 </select>

<select id="filter-select">
<option value="green">green</option>
<option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The id must be unique.

Comment: You can't select white AND black from the same drop down. Do you mean white OR black?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st : as @Danny said Id must be unique .. you shouldn't use same Id for more than one element

2nd:if I got your point you want if user choose white from first select and say blue from second select then redirect

so your html code should be

```
<select class="filter-select" id="filter-select1">
   <option value="white">white</option>
   <option value="black">black</option>
 </select>

<select class="filter-select" id="filter-select2">
   <option value="green">green</option>
   <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
```

and jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.filter-select').on('change',function(){
        var thisVal = $(this).val();
        var anotherVal = $('.filter-select').not($(this)).val();
        if(thisVal == 'white' && anotherVal == 'blue' || 
           anotherVal == 'white' && thisVal == 'blue'){
            window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
        }
    });
});
```

This code will redirect to https://stackoverflow.com/  if user choose white from first select  and blue from second select

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/h631h541/7/)

> > Notes:  1- don't forget to include jquery
> >             2- This code may work just in your case with two select elements .. if you have more of this select elements with same class
> >     code may not work